# mongodb pull nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to pull multiple objects from array.

Here is my sample collection:

**Users**

```json
    {
        "_id": "wef324DGSshf",
        "userTypes": [
            {
                "type": "students",
                "users": [
                    {
                        "name": "John",
                        "age": 20
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Mike",
                        "age": 20
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Henry",
                        "age": 30
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Henry",
                        "age": 40
                    }
                ]
                
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to pull those objects where:
`type: "students"` and `ages: [20,40]`

So I have these 2 inputs: `type` & `ages`

**Expected Response:**

```json
    {
        "_id": "wef324DGSshf",
        "userTypes": [
            {
                "type": "students",
                "users": [              
                    {
                        "name": "Henry",
                        "age": 30
                    }
                ]
                
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have tried this query so far but it is not working:

```json
    Users.update({
        "userTypes.type": "students",
        "userTypes.users.age": {$in: [20, 40]},
    },
    { 
        $pull: { 
            "userTypes": { 
                "userTypes.users.$.age": {$in: [20, 40]}
            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrayFilters to specify the filtering for `"type": "students"` and normally perform `$pull` on `age`

```js
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$pull": {
    "userTypes.$[ut].users": {
      "age": {
        $in: [
          20,
          40
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "ut.type": "students"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vbGBq6xuGH8)

---

Explanation: Check out the [official doc about arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/). You can think of the entries in arrayFilters as predicates. For a variable `ut`, it needs to have `type: students`. Let's go back to the `$pull` part. The predicate is applied to `userTypes`. That means for an entry in userTypes, ut, it needs to fit in the predicate of `type: students`. At the same time, we are `$pull`ing the entries that age is in [20, 40].

Comment: Can you explain this query a bit? What does ut means here?

Comment: @StormTrooper updated the answer with explanation